# Importing a class from another directory

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions worked for me.
So let's say I have a directory structured as follow :

```
folder1:
 -- file1.py
folder2:
 -- class2.py
```

I want to call the class from `class2.py` in my `file1.py` so what I did at the start of the `file1.py` is

```
from folder2.class2 import Class2
```

But the following issue arises:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'
```

so I tried something else:

```
from .folder2.class2 import Class2
```

the following issue arises:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I read a solution on the site where you add  `__init.py__` in the `folder2`
but it didn't help.

Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Comment: 1. Make sure the root directory (the one that contains `folder1` and `folder2`) is on your `PYTHONPATH`.  2. Make sure `folder1` and `folder2` each contain an `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert any path into your sys via the `sys.path.insert` method:

```
import sys
path = '\\'.join(__file__.split("\\")[:-2])
sys.path.insert(1, path)

from folder2.class2 import Class2
```

In the above code I made it so that the directory holding folders `folder1` and `folder2` gets inserted into the system. If the location of the directories is fixed, a more clear way would be to directly use the path of the folder:

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop'
sys.path.insert(1, path)
```

Comment: thank you but this didn't work either still got the ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: @OneManArmy With the first code or the second code in my answer?

Comment: with the first code, I didnt try the second because I will dockerize the application therefore I dont think it's a good idea to use C:\\Users\\...

Comment: @OneManArmy Try replacing the `\\\` with `/` then.

Answer (score 0):

folder1:
-- __init__.py
-- file1.py
folder2:
-- __init__.py
-- class2.py

in `class2.py`:

```
class Class2():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    ...
```

in `file1.py`:

```
import sys
sys.append('..')
from folder2.class2 import Class2
```